# Wordpress+WP-stateless+google cloud storage , I have a problem that image path url change of Feature Image when next month

Tags: wordpress

For example,

File Url of image was changed from "gcp../2024/01/a.png to "gcp../2024/02/a.png" every month by automatically but not me.

I configed mode to stateless mode in WP-stateless.

How to solve and Why

Please help

Comment: Have you found a solution? I face this exact issue